# How to prevent gradle from querying other repositories for dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm having an issue where gradle looks into repositories where the required dependency isn't stored and the build fails.

E.g gradle looks into http://pay.cards/maven and https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/

while the required dependency is mentioned in the gradle file

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0).
  Required by:
      project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1
      project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1
      project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:15.0.1
      project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:15.0.1
   > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
      > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://pay.cards/maven/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml.
         > org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 3; The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.
   > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
      > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml.
         > Could not get resource 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml'.
            > Could not GET 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

while this works on some machines and not on others, how to solve this?